# Python printing inline with a sleep command

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is the following code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep

def print_inline():
    print("Hello ", end='')
    sleep(5)
    print("World")

print_inline()
```

waits until the sleep is done to print `Hello World`, shouldn't print `Hello` then wait for 5 seconds and print `World` in the same line?

Comment: Did you try setting `flush=True` in the first `print()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flush output of Python print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.  "Hello" sits in the output buffer until there's a reason to flush it to the output device.  In this case, that "reason" is the end of the program.  If you want The delayed effect, add

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

just before your sleep statement.

See also a more complete discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print).

Answer (score 4):

If you set the first `print` to:

```
print("Hello ", end='', flush=True)
```

this should print `Hello`, then sleep for 5, then print `World`.

Edit: this only works in Python 3, didn't see the Python 2.7 tag...

Comment: Thanks @McGlothlin. This wouldn't work on python2.7 though, `# TypeError: 'flush' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Oops, I'm using Python 3 so didn't catch that! Let me see how you'd do this in Python 2.7...

Comment: @MustafaS it looks like Prune has what you want. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This is used to force the Python's print function to screen.
***See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print) also.***